# Passing Data with without Segue from Container View to MainVC

Tags: ios, swift, containers, segue, viewcontroller

Idea to send value trackNumber after pressing the button in the Container View(with ViewController) to Main ViewController to recivedTrackNumber without segue because they are in the same view. How to inform Main View controller(recivedTrackNumber) about the value of trackNumber ?

Container View(with ViewController) looks like that with button

```
 import UIKit
 class SelectSoundVC: UIViewController {

   var trackNumber: Int!

   @IBAction func winterSoundBut(_ sender: UIButton) {
    trackNumber = 1

  } 

}
```

and Main ViewController

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {

   var recivedTrackNumber: Int!

}
```

[Main.storyboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Wiv.png)

Comment: What do you mean by in the same view ???

Comment: Updated a screenshot please take a look. Container view in The Main VC. That's what i mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Delegate` pattern should help you. First of all you need the delegate protocol:

```
protocol SelectSoundVCDelegate {
    func didSelectTrackNumber(_ trackNumber: Int)
}
```

with func that accept the `trackNumber` value. Next, you need to create `delegate` property in `SelectSoundVC`:

```
class SelectSoundVC: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: SelectSoundVCDelegate?
    var trackNumber: Int!

    @IBAction func winterSoundBut(_ sender: UIButton) {
        trackNumber = 1
        delegate?.didSelectTrackNumber(trackNumber)
    } 

}
```

that will be call the `didSelectTrackNumber` in `@IBAction`. Note that `delegate` property should be weak to avoid reference cycles. The last step, in `MainVC` you should set `delegate` property of `SelectSoundVC`:

```
selectSoundVC.delegate = self
```

This part is little bit tricky, because you need the instance of `SelectSoundVC` to set the delegate. You can set it in `prepareFoSegue` method, for example:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let viewController = segue.destination as? SelectSoundVC, segue.identifier == "SelectSoundVC" {
        viewController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: That's working perfectly thx for the hint with prepareForSegue.

Answer (score 0):

Third method ;-)
If you instantiate the second view controller from code (from the MainVC), then you could access that variable easily:

```
let selectSoundVC = SelectSoundVC()
recivedTrackNumber = selectSoundVC.trackNumber
present(selectSoundVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This should work!

Answer (score -1):

You can use prepareForSegue(_:) to retrieve a strong reference to your embedded view controller at initialization. Just set your segue identifier to "EmbedSegue" in Storyboard

```
// MainVC
private var embeddedViewController: SelectSoundVC?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? SelectSoundVC,
        segue.identifier == "EmbedSegue" {
        self.embeddedViewController = vc
    }
}
```

Also change your track property to an optional as no track can be selected.

```
// SelectSoundVC
var trackNumber: Int?
```

Then from anywhere in your MainVC you can retrieve your track number :

```
// Here you can access to the trackNumber property, no need to duplicate its value (Single Responsability)
if let embeddedViewController = self.embeddedViewController, let trackNumber = embeddedViewController.trackNumber {
    print("Track Number \(trackNumber)")
}
```